# Is it possible to disable requesting permissions at runtime android 6 and make it work normally from AndroidManifest?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to disable requesting permissions at runtime android 6 and make it work normally from AndroidManifest?

I.e. when you install the app it requests permissions like it was on previous versions of android?

Comment: Below answers are just a work around. Be aware of the fact that your target sdk should always be the highest one.

Comment: As the answers state, it is possible, but **not** recommended. You should keep up to the latest stuff.

Comment: Simply answer _No_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple solution:

Change `targetSdkVersion` inside application `build.gradle` to 22.

Then all application permission are granted during installation.

However, this won't prevent the user from going to phone settings and manually turning them off. Your app will then crash.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It is possible 
In your module gradle file Change targetsdk version

> targetSdkVersion 22

Not this will only work if you havn't upload it on play store with targetsdk as 23.

Comment: Kindly accept or vote up the answer if it helps you. :)

Comment: I voted up but it won't cast for some reason, I don't know why

Comment: You can accept answer as corrected if it works ... If its not casting then also then its ok You problem is resolved so cheers !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Developers abused permissions in android by requiring nearly everything. This rendered the whole permission management system nearly useless because it is really hard to find an application which requires only permissions which it really needs for it's functioning. With regret users had to grant permissions which they do not want to grant. So a little of tyranny was needed to revive the system. You must request every permission separately now and you must somehow handle denial of some of the permissions. This is the only correct way.

So as not to break all existing applications there is a compatibility mode. If you build with targetSdkVersion 22 then you get old behaviour. But you also do not get all shiny new features. So you will not be able to live with 22'nd SDK forever and you will have to accept new rules.